# Spring - delete record from DB and from list

Tags: java, spring, jsp, controller

I write simple app that let us writing, updating and removing posts. So far I can write and update, but my delete command seems to not work. Here is my jsp code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="post" items="${listOfPosts}">
        <tr>
            <td>${post.id}</td>
            <td>${post.title}</td>
            <td>${post.author}</td>
            <td>
                <a href="<c:url value="/editPost/${post.id}" />" >Edit</a>

                <form:form action="deletePost" method="post" commandName="deletedBlogpost">
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete post">
                </form:form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

and my controller methods, where I tried to implement Post-Redirect-Get Pattern:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "deletePost", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String deletePostPOST (@ModelAttribute("deletedBlogpost") BlogPost blogpost, BindingResult bindingResult, RedirectAttributes ra) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {

            return ERROR_PAGE_VIEW;
        }

        repo.delete(blogpost);
        ra.addFlashAttribute("blogpost", blogpost);

        return "redirect:/delete-success";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "delete-success", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String deletePostGET(@ModelAttribute("deletedBlogpost") BlogPost blogpost, Model model){

        model.addAttribute(M_LIST_OF_POSTS, repo.findAll());

        return RESULT_PAGE_VIEW;
    }
```

I guess it has to be something with jsp form, because my code isn't even reaching controller's code. Any help will be appreciated, 'casue I'm still a beginner here and I am still struggling with basics.

*EDIT* here is my entity BlogPost

```
@Entity
@Table(name="posts")
public class BlogPost {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="post_title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name="post_content")
    private String content;

    @Column(name="post_author", nullable = false)
    private String author;

    public BlogPost(){}

    public BlogPost(String title, String content, String author) {
        this.title = title;
        this.content = content;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "ID: "+getId()+", tytul: "+getTitle()+", tresc: "+getContent()+", autor: "+getAuthor()+"\n";
    }

}
```

and my application.properties where I can establish a PostgreSQL connection:

```
#PostgreSQL
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/blogdatabase
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

EDIT:
I tried to solve it by adding to jsp form

```
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="${post.id}"/>
```

and by adding to deletePostPost method

```
repo.delete(deletedBlogpost.getId());
```

Nothing has changed. Clicking button isn't calling any action.

Comment: You need to send the ID of the post to delete. Your form currently sends nothing at all. So your server can't possibly know which post to delete. Use a hidden input field. No need to send the whole blog post information to delete it. The ID is sufficient.

Comment: Also, "my delete command seems to not work" is much too vague. You must learn to diagnose the problems better than that: use your debugger to see which method is called, what the variable values are. Add logging statements to the code. Inspect the requests and responses sent by the browser, using its dev tools, etc.

Comment: try action like /deletePost. It should work. Then as suggested by @JBNizet Pass the id for the post so server will come to know which post needs to be deleted. As these are the Rest based calls I would suggest you to use proper HttpMethod method (i.e. in this case DELETE).

Comment: Your <form> is inside forEach loop.You are creating multiple forms inside table with same name. Try removing <form> and handle it using <a> onclick event.

Comment: @Vino having several forms doesn't cause any problem, and there is no need for JavaScript to submit a POST request.

Comment: @JB Nizet Got it..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

yourRepository.deleteById(id)

Comment: Hi Florin. Usually answers with explanation collect more up wotes. Would you like to update your answer with explanation?